# Odoo 12 Record Change

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am a starter in odoo.in CRM Module ,manager should be notified 90 days prior to expiry of field (subscription) and automatically

Can anyone help me to achieve this goal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Required basic knowledge of JS.

If you want to send automatic mail on expiration then here is a trick:

- Go to your enterprise addons folder then search for a
  **web_enterprise** module.
- Their is **static** folder , in that folder you'll find
  **home_menu.js**.
- In this js you'll find method like **_enterpriseExpirationCheck**.
- Go to that method and their is a variable called diffDays (calculated
  days of your expiration validity).
- Put your condition like : `if (diffDays === 30)` then make **rpc**
  call to send mail with python.

That's it.

You'll find RPC call example in:

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-do-web-rpc-requests-in-javascript-22835

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47194770/how-to-call-python-function-in-jquery-in-odoo-11